# How to use Countif function to count rows that has a specific value in either of column A or B in Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I am trying to count the number of rows that has a specific value let say "John" in either Column C or Column D. If the two columns have both the same value, then only one of them is counted.

Here is the example sheet. column C & D has the data.
Column G contains the function countif

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9I2bhtlHAMWqVqdE7hbkgLRLCCUrfnOMSQcf9Gj4_0/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(C5:D12,F5:F7)-COUNTIFS(C5:C12,F5:F7,D5:D12,F5:F7))
```

[image]